# REST Web services and the HTTP protocol

Tags: rest

As per my understanding and googling found the following: RESTful Web services are not protocol dependent and can be built on any other protocol apart from HTTP protocol.

Question: If the above said statement is true, how will REST handle the operations with different methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc). Aren't these methods HTTP specification dependent and may not be available in other protocols?

Comment: what you read and where link your reference

Answer (score 2):

REST is an architectural style, meaning it is some set of constraints you have to fulfill to be "compliant". See exact description in Fielding's dissertation: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

Now, HTTP is build upon these principles, arguably that is why it became so successful, so it is already a system which is distributed, cacheable, etc. That is why we can use it to build RESTful services/resources on top of it. REST itself does not define any exact set of operations, HTTP does that (GET, POST, etc.).

So in theory, you could design another RESTful system without HTTP, without the operations GET/POST/etc., but practically nobody does that and you should probably stick with HTTP.